# Where do these spans come from? <span class="goog_qs-tidbit goog_qs-tidbit-0">

Tags: html, google-search, plagiarism-detection, blackboard

We reluctantly used blackboard to give a test and several students have answers with loads of HTML formatting.  I can imagine writing answers in Word and copy/pasting answers adds formatting.  But i see this span tag: `<span class="goog_qs-tidbit goog_qs-tidbit-0">` a few times.  I thought it might come from a google search but haven't been able to find it on google or on the site that he copied from.  Does anyone know who uses these spans?

Playing digital sleuth like this is fun but pretty depressing.
Note to all students-- When you copy/paste something from the internet, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try open page in incognito mode in Chrome (ctrl+shift+n) , should works good. Some plugins make this error